# How do I extract a list of values from a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have loads of files on Linux to process. What I want to do is extract a certain table of numbers from those files.

Each file is long, but contains a table like this:

```
----------------  
2017     2018  
----------------   
0.44     -0.5  
0.28     0.66  
0.378    0.57  
-0.56    0.24  
----------------
```

In each file, the table has 2017 and 2018, but the numbers below them are different. And the position of the table in each file is different.

I hope to get these numbers from each file, and paste them into a new file, and add a name for each line to the table. What I hope it will look like in the new file is like this:

```
Group A  0.44   -0.5   
Group B  0.28   0.66   
Group C  0.378  0.57    
Group D  -0.56  0.24
```

So which Bash command allows me to do this work for hundreds of files? And if you don't recommend Bash, what other things do you recommend me to use (hopefully it's easy to use)?
I've just learned how to use Linux, and I know no programming languages.

Comment: What have you tried? Along with that post representative examples of how the location and position of your input can vary within your input files.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've tried what John Zwinck said (see below), but so far it doesn't work yet.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand why someone downvoted my question. If you think my question isn't clear, you can ask me for clarification. I think I've made everything clear though.

Comment: Some times there is no telling, maybe the phase of the moon, who knows. At least it is better now than it used to be. It now costs the downvoter 1-rep to downvote, while it costs you 2. It's not free anymore and you can only loose a max of 10-rep. There used to be cadres of downvote weenies that when one downvotes, they all would. Just don't sweat it, it all comes out in the wash. Best thing you can do is always post [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will result in more upvotes than downvotes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for this. I didn't know about this. But in this case I can't post 'A Minimal, Complete, blahblahblah' cos I don't have my own code. I have no idea which command can help me do this task. And now I'm surprised John Zwinck's answer is no longer there! I'm new to this platform, and now I feel so confused....

Comment: What does `grep -A5 '2017     2018' file` tell you for the different files? Does it locate the `'2017     2018'` correctly in each file. If not try `grep -A5 '2017[[:space:]][[:space:]]*2018' file` do making the whitespace between them help?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It works! Thanks. And then how do I add the group names to each line?

Comment: If that works, then you could get close with `awk 'BEGIN{ /2017[[:space:]][[:space:]]*2018/ split ("ABCDEF", a, ""); i = 0 } /^[-]*[0-9]/ { if (i == 0) {i++; next} printf "%s %s  %s\n", "Group", a[i++], $0 }' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can test and produce these kind of script in bash. But I will suggest you to do step by step.

Go for single file and create script which will produce your new file like this:

```
Group A 0.44 -0.5
Group B 0.28 0.66
Group C 0.378 0.57
Group D -0.56 0.24
```

After testing, go for multiple files and create bash script that will take values from each file and produce.

Comment: Yeah but I wonder which Bash command allows me to do this job?